# Uitableview separator line effect in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is possible to create this separator style effect programmatically?
I have tried adding a uiview with an image created with photoshop but doesn't work very well.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would simply set `separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and in the cell view add a UIImageView subview that has the separator you want at the bottom.

Comment: This separator line has 2 colors, so I recommend you to use 2 UIImageView subviews. One with light gray color on the top of the cell, and second with black color at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `separatorStyle` and `separatorColor` on the table view. You can also add views with images or simply background colours and transparency to the top / bottom of your cells.

---

It looks like you could just set the `tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];` and add a 1px high view to the top of your cell with a white background and `alpha = 0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting a background image to your view and make tablecell seperator color `[UIColor clearColor]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:132.0f/255.0f green:132.0f/255.0f blue:131.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```